# Mobile web, how to retain selected text on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-website, textselection

I have been looking at using something like jQuery Text Editor (http://jqueryte.com/) to provide some simple html editing capabilities on a mobile app using the mobile web. When I use jQ TE on a mobile device, I can obviously select text, but the moment I then try to say bolden or italicize the selected text (i.e. a subsequent touch event has now occurred) the highlighted text is "lost" and  cannot be acted on.

So far, the best I can do, is first select say bold, and then type some text, and this is not great as it essentially does not allow for editing.

How can I retain the selection on touch. I imagine there is some javascript way of doing this.